# configure setup.py in order to provide multiple installation mode

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

Is there any solution to create specific installation of a python package with setup.py ?

I wanted to install different modules based on some parameters which would be given to pip.

**Edit**

Maybe, my first message was unclear, I will try below a better explanation.

We have a shared python package in order to share some code to the entire company tech worker. This package is in a private repo and installable via pip.

Sadly, this package is becoming to big and we now face some performance issue when trying to install it.

I was wondering if it was possible, somehow to create a custom setup.py script that will allow user to install only small part of the module and not the entire one.

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe what you really want is https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ ??

Comment: What you *should* do is to migrate things out of that package into specialised packages. How big did you manage to make the package to cause performance issues on install, however?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a line in your `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    # ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    # ...
)
```

to fix your problem you need to work with this `find_packages` method, this function returns a list python packages in this project

so the solution is simple get users args for setup.py and based on that return a selection of `find_packages`

here is a simplified code

```
if '--full' in sys.argv:
    packages = find_packages()
elif '--only-module-a':
    packages = [p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('a')]

setup(
    # ...
    packages=packages,
    # ...
)
```

PS: as @hoefling commented this solution is a hacky, and may cause misunderstanding for users, you should separate package into smaller subpackages (you can still keep them in one repo)

Comment: Thanks ! Just don't understand how to install the module then. `pip install modulename --full` won't work as `--full` is not a pip option.

Comment: use `python setup.py install --full`

Comment: No offense, but that's a bad solution. A distribution package is atomic and can't be further divided. Now I will be able to install the package with the same metadata, but a different codebase. If I want to declare a dependency to this package, there's no way to specify what "edition" of it I need. The only _real_ solution is what @MartijnPieters wrote in his comment - split the big package into small ones, potentially collecting the codebase of the package suite under a namespace package if necessary.

Comment: @hoefling yeah, you are right. maybe creating multiple setup.py is better idea (instead of parsing args). but I agree with you the final solution is separating the package itself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a text file of all the packages you have installed, edit the packages and versions you want inside that text file, and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install it somewhere else?